# How to create a python instance that has another class object linked to it?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, attributes, instance

If I have a simple class like below:

```
class Usr:     
    def __init__(self, time_r):
        self.time_range = time_r
```

where I want the attribute`time_r` to be an object of class `TimeRange` like below:

```
class TimeRange:
    def __init__(self, min_time, max_time):
        self.ti = min_time
        self.tf = max_time
```

I would like to create an empty instance of Usr `s = Usr` and then assign the attributes later. Example: `s.time_range.ti = 5` , `s.time_range.tf = 10`

In other words `time_r` in `Usr` should be an attribute that will automatically create an instance of `TimeRange` for that `Usr` instance

How can one link the two classes in the manner above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could set initializers to default values (e.g. `None`):

```
class TimeRange:
    def __init__(self, min_time=None, max_time=None):
        self.ti = min_time
        self.tf = max_time

class Usr:     
    def __init__(self, time_r=None):
        self.time_range = time_r if time_r is not None else TimeRange()
```

then:

```
s = Usr()
s.time_range.ti = 5
s.time_range.tf = 10
```

you may want to set more reasonable default values for `TimeRange`...